# How to compare a vector to a map

Tags: c++, class, vector, dictionary, switch-statement

Okay so I have an `inventory` class that accesses a static vector from my base class `MainShop`. I also have a `SwordShop` class which inherits from `MainShop`. (Both Inventory and SwordShop are derived classes).

```
//SwordShop class
void SwordShop::Shop
{
//I have a setter function where it takes an integer and a string and adds its to my hashmap.
//Also have a getter function which has a for loop displaying my items in my map
this->setWeaponSoldier(1, "1) Meito Ichimonji\n   +4 Damage\n   150Gold");
this->setWeaponSoldier(2, "2) Shusui\n   +10 Damage\n   230Gold");
this->setWeaponSoldier(3, "3) Elixir\n   +16 Damage\n   300Gold");
this->setWeaponSoldier(4, "4) Blade of scars\n   +24 Damage\n   550Gold");
this->setWeaponSoldier(5, "5) Ragnarok\n   +32 Damage\n   610Gold");
this->setWeaponSoldier(6, "6) Eternal Darkness\n   +40 Damage\n   690Gold");
this->setWeaponSoldier(7, "7) Masamune\n   +52 Damage\n   750Gold");
this->setWeaponSoldier(8, "8) Soul Calibur\n   +60 Damage\n   900Gold");

}

//Function in my inventory class
void Inventory::DisplayInventory()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "\nWhat do you want to do?\n1) Check Status\n2) Equip Weapons\n";//Equip what is in your inventory
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1: this->DisplayStats();
            break;
        case 2:cout << WeaponInventory.size() << endl;//debug
            if (!WeaponInventory.empty())//Make sure inventory is not empty
            {
                cout << "Your current Weapons are: \n";
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < WeaponInventory.size(); ++i)
                    cout << i+1 << ") " << WeaponInventory[i] << endl;//cout whats currently in my inventory
                cout << "What item weapon would you like to equip?";
                /***********Here is the problem*******************/
                //how can I make the user choose the actual and correct item in the inventory?
                //cin >> equipChoice;
                //code goes here
            }
            else cout << "Error! You currently do not own any items\n";
            break;
  }
```

So for example lets say the user adds `Meito Ichimonji` into my `WeaponInventory` vector and then adds another one. How can I make the user have the ability to pick the right item? Im looking for something like this:

```
//PseudoCode
Displays my inventory with for loop
I have two items in it which user buys
1)Meito Ichimonji
and 
2)Elixir
cout << "what would you like to equip?";
cin >> equipChoice
if (equipChoice == 1)//chooses whatever item is first
check to see what the attack that the weapon has and add it to my attack
attack += 20;//lets say the sword had 20 attack
else if (equipChoice == 2)//chooses whatever is second
do something else
etc...
```

Sorry if I have not explained it clearly, but I tried my best!

Comment: i think the best way for you is to make an item class as well, which can contains name, stats of the item. Then in this code you can easily select the item from the vector and just add the item to your equipment class and let it deal with the calculations.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an issue of coding/code-design but rather a conceptual design issue. I would propose to start from a blank slate and formalise the design, possibly using a 'relational' perspective, even though you might not use an RDMS in an implementation (or some other formalism like UML) just to put some clear stakes in the ground. At least such model would give a clear view of the relationships between the various entities and help understanding what is needed in order to access/retrieve information from the model. Most likely the code will then be the least you'll have to worry about.